# Which theories explain that given a choice of hard and easy tasks one would pick the easy one?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, reference-request, motivation, behavior

Which theories deal with cost benefit analysis? For example, given a binary choice of hard and easy tasks (eg. Picking low hanging fruit, stealing what is not bolted down, cheating on a test, taking a spacial shortcut/jaywalking) one would exhibit preference towards the easy one. How can that be explained from behavioral, evolutionary or cognitive perspective? I need studies or names.

Comment: Behavioural economics?